# Difference between these two declaration of vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Using the 1st method declare the vector show some different behavior than the other. 4
For ex - If the vector declared with the **1st way contains data such as [1,1,2,1,3,3,2]**
and if we use the method of vector size as `vectorname[1].size() this returns the number of occurrences of 1 in the vector and same for vectorname[2].size() or vectorname[3].size().`

```
1.vector<int> data[size];//1st method[1][Contains VScode snap][1]
```

But, using the 2nd method to declare the vector it gives and error in VScode(version 1.50.1) with the problem information as -"**Expression must have a class type**

```
2.vector<int> data(size);//2nd method[2][Contains VScode snap][2]
```

[1]https://i.stack.imgur.com/1je43.jpg
[2]https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHYMB.jpg

Comment: The first one creates an **array** of `size` empty vectors. The second creates **one** vector with `size` elements.

Comment: 1st method you do not declare a vector, you declare array of vectors. As why second variant does not compile provide [mcve]

Comment: If anyone can help please do help without down voting it. Thank You.

Comment: At the moment nobody can help but  you with asking proper question, hense the downvotes

Comment: @Slava Thank you for answering. It clears most of my doubts. Sorry, if it wasn't a proper question to ask. I tried seraching about it but didn't found any suitable resources about it. It would be great if you can share something useful related to this. Thank You.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thank you for answering. I understand the difference between these two.

Comment: I did not mean this is not proper question to ask but you did not formulate it properly so there is no enough information to help you.

Comment: Your title asks what the difference is.

Comment: @Slava Sorry for that i don't usually post a lot of stuff so i don't have much clue. Though thank you for helping me out.

Comment: Don't add links to pictures of code and error messages. Add the code and error messages as plain text inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

The first method does not declare a single `vector`, it declares an array of `size` number of empty `vector`s. The second method does create a vector with `size` zero-initialized ints, and it should compile. The reason you're getting an error is unclear from what you have given us, but it seems like it may be because your compiler is not recognizing the `vector` name, because you have not included `<vector>` or did not write `std::` before `vector`.

Comment: In second method it must be the compiler error. Sorry for not adding the whole picture related to it but i have added using namespace std above so there would be no need to add std:: vector or something like this again in the code. Thank You for answering.

Answer (score 0):

As for the compiler error in your picture (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHYMB.jpg), what you do there is:

```
vector<int> data(n + 1);
...
data->push_back(x);
```

Note that `data` is *not* a pointer. But `->` (the *arrow operator*) is the syntax for calling a method *through a pointer*.
Simply change the line to

```
data.push_back(x);
```

(With your other method, it was valid syntax because you had an array of vectors, and `data->push_back[x];` would in that case push back x to the first vector in your array. Semantically doubtful for the given context, but still valid syntax.)

Another error in the code is that you later have `data[1].size()`. `data[1]` is the second element in the vector and thus of type integer. An integer does not have a method `size()`.

(With your other method, this again would be valid syntax, but as every vector save for the first would be of length zero, you could instead also write `int ans = 0;`.)

Two other errors I see:

I assume that the minimum is meant to be taken over the values in the vector instead of their nonexistent sizes. If so, then your code assumes that `data[3]` exists. But the length of your vector is a user input, at might be as little as 1. In that case, not even `data[1]` would exist, and you would get a segmentation fault during runtime when trying to access those elements.

Second, you first create a vector of length n+1 without initializing the values, and then you push back another n elements. After that, your vector will have length 2n+1. This is valid code, but I strongly believe that instead you wanted a vector of length n+1. If so, instead of `data.push_back(x);` you want to go with `data[i] = x;`. Alternatively, create the vector as zero length vector and then use your `push_back`s. (The other way is better, though.)

As a remark, it seems to me you want to access the ith element of a vector with `[i]` instead of `[i-1]`, and you use `n+1` for the vectors length instead of `n` for that reason. While this not wrong per se, it is unusual for C++.
Also, on stack overflow, it is discouraged to post pictures like you did, at least without good reason. Directly post the code (and the error output) as text instead. Note that the single line of the vector initialization you actually wrote in your post is totally fine, and your error happened at another line you did not wrote out and is only present in the picture. Always post the whole code (or if you have more than a few lines, create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).